# spark sql Find the number of extensions for a record

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, relation

I have a dataset as below

| col1 | extension_col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2345 | 2246 |
| 2246 | 2134 |
| 2134 | 2091 |
| 2091 | Null |
| 1234 | 1111 |
| 1111 | Null |

I need to find the number of extensions available for each record in `col1` whereby records are sorted already and contiguously in terms of sets which are terminated by a `null`.

the final result as below

| col1 | extension_col1 | No_Of_Extensions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 2246 | 3 |
| 2246 | 2134 | 2 |
| 2134 | 2091 | 1 |
| 2091 | Null | 0 |
| 1234 | 1111 | 1 |
| 1111 | Null | 0 |

value 2345 extends as `2345>2246>2134>2091>null` and hence it has 3 extension relations excluding null.

How to get the 3rd column(`No_Of_Extensions`) using spark sql/scala?

Comment: It's not clear, what is an "_extension_"? How do you order your dataframe? (column `col1`?)

Comment: Can be done but fiddly. Not really a spark use.

Comment: @blackbishop yes, order by col1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using some Window functions. First, using a cumulative conditional sum on `extension_col1`, create a group column `grp`. Then, using `row_number` function on a window partitioned by `grp` and ordered by `col1` but this time on ascending you get the desired result:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  (Some(99985), Some(94904)), (Some(94904), Some(89884)),
  (Some(89884), Some(88592)), (Some(88592), Some(86367)),
  (Some(86367), Some(84121)), (Some(84121), None)
).toDF("col1", "extension_col1")

val w1 = Window.orderBy(desc("col1"))
val w2 = Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy("col1")

val result = df.withColumn(
    "grp",
    sum(when(col("extension_col1").isNull, 1).otherwise(0)).over(w1)
).withColumn(
    "No_Of_Extensions",
    when(col("extension_col1").isNull, 0).otherwise(row_number().over(w2))
).drop("grp").orderBy(desc("col1"))

result.show
                        
//+-----+--------------+----------------+
//| col1|extension_col1|No_Of_Extensions|
//+-----+--------------+----------------+
//|99985|         94904|               5|
//|94904|         89884|               4|
//|89884|         88592|               3|
//|88592|         86367|               2|
//|86367|         84121|               1|
//|84121|          null|               0|
//+-----+--------------+----------------+
```

Note that the first `sum` is using a non partitioned window, so all the data will be moved into one partition and thus could affect performances.

---

Spark-SQL equivalent query:

```sql
SELECT col1, 
       extension_col1, 
       case when extension_col1 is null then 0 else row_number() over(partition by grp order by col1) end as No_Of_Extensions
FROM  (
      SELECT *, 
             sum(case when extension_col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) over(order by col1 desc) as grp
      FROM df
)
ORDER BY col1 desc
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. for few records its coming up as below

/+----+--------------+----------------+
//|col1|extension_col1|No_Of_Extensions|
//+----+--------------+----------------+
//|99985|          94904|               2|
//|94904|          89884|               1|
//|89884|          88592|               1|
//|88592|          86367|               1|
//|86367|         84121|               5|
//| 84121 |          null|               0|
//+----+--------------+----------------+

Comment: @maverick9143 Not sure how you got this result, I just tested it with the same data as you and it gives correct result. Please see my edit with full working example.

Comment: could you please try for the below dataset

+-----+--------------+
| col1|extension_col1|
+-----+--------------+
|99985|         94904|
|94904|         89884|
|89884|         88592|
|88592|         86367|
|86367|         84121|
|84121|          null|
| 2345|          2246|
| 2246|          2134|
| 2134|          2091|
| 2091|          null|
|94800|         89900|
|89900|          null|
+-----+--------------+

Comment: for the above daatset output should be like below
| col1|extension_col1|No_Of_Extensions|
|99985|         94904|               5|
|94904|         89884|               4|
|89884|         88592|               3|
|88592|         86367|               2|
|86367|         84121|               1|
|84121|          null|               0|
|94800|         89900|               1|
|89900|          null|               0|
| 2345|          2246|               3|
| 2246|          2134|               2|
| 2134|          2091|               1|
| 2091|          null|               0|

Comment: But its comming as below
| col1|extension_col1|No_Of_Extensions|
+-----+--------------+----------------+
|99985|         94904|               3|
|94904|         89884|               2|
|94800|         89900|               1|
|89900|          null|               0|
|89884|         88592|               3|
|88592|         86367|               2|
|86367|         84121|               1|
|84121|          null|               0|
| 2345|          2246|               3|
| 2246|          2134|               2|
| 2134|          2091|               1|
| 2091|          null|               0|

Comment: @maverick9143 You said that your order by `col` so why do you have value `89884` before `89900` in your result? The code works by using ordering on `col1`, without ordering you can't achieve this as dataframe are unordered.

Comment: @blackishop, I have re-ordered the expected output for visualization purposes. Apologies for the inconvenience. Here is the expected output
| col1|extension_col1|No_Of_Extensions| 
|99985| 94904| 5| 
|94904| 89884| 4| 
|94800| 89900| 1|
|89900| null| 0| 
|89884| 88592| 3|
|88592| 86367| 2| 
|86367| 84121| 1| 
|84121| null| 0| 
| 2345| 2246| 3| 
| 2246| 2134| 2| 
| 2134| 2091| 1| 
| 2091| null| 0|

because the relation of col1 with extension_col1 is as below
for 99985 : 99985 -> 94904 -> 89884 -> 88592 -> 86367 -> 84121 -> None
for 94800: 94800 -> 89900 -> None

Comment: Continuity 
for 2345 : 2345 -> 2246 -> 2134 -> 2091 -> None.

I was getting mismatch because there are few individual values in col1 that are not an extension to the previous col1 like incase of for col1 record i.e 99985, we have 94800 which is a separate value that is independent/no-relation on the extensions of 99985. but as we are doing on an order basis instead of extension relation I was getting mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

> An alternative to the blackbishop in that I assume the data may not
> always be ordered, and hence do some alternative processing. I like the conditional summing, but not applicable here.
>
> In all honesty a bad use case for Spark at scale as I can also not get around single
> partition aspect either as the other answer states. But partitioning size is increased on newer Spark
> versions and may the ' lists'  are long in this example.

**Part 1 - Generate data**

```
// 1. Generate data.
val df = Seq(( Some(2345), Some(22246) ), ( Some(22246), Some(2134) ), ( Some(2134), Some(2091) ), (Some(2091), None) ,
              ( Some(1234), Some(1111) ), ( Some(1111), None )
             ).toDF("col1" ,"extCol1")
```

**Part 2 - Actual processing**

```
//2. Narrow transform, add position in dataset as values nay not awlays be desc or asc.
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}
val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowid", LongType, false)))
val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex
val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)  // Some cost


//3. Make groupings in record ranges. Cannot avoid the single partition aspects, so this only works if we can do it with data that can fit into a single partition. At scale one would 
//   not be able to do this really unless some grouping characteristic. 
val dfg = df2.filter(df2("extCol1").isNull)

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val winSpec1 = Window.orderBy(asc("rowid"))

val dfg2 = dfg.withColumn("prev_rowid_tmp", lag("rowid", 1, -1).over(winSpec1))
              .withColumn("rowidFrom", $"prev_rowid_tmp" + 1)
              .drop("prev_rowid_tmp")
              .drop("extCol1")
              .withColumnRenamed("rowid","rowidTo")

//4. Apply grouping of ranges of rows to data.
val df3 = df2.as("df2").join(dfg2.as("dfg2"), 
          $"df2.rowid" >= $"dfg2.rowidFrom" && $"df2.rowid" <= $"dfg2.rowidTo", "inner")             

//5. Do the calcs.
val res = df3.withColumn("numExtensions", $"rowidTo" - $"rowid") 
res.select("df2.col1", "extCol1", "numExtensions").show(false)
```

returns:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+
|col1 |extCol1|numExtensions|
+-----+-------+-------------+
|2345 |22246  |3            |
|22246|2134   |2            |
|2134 |2091   |1            |
|2091 |null   |0            |
|1234 |1111   |1            |
|1111 |null   |0            |
+-----+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario where the data table’s first column is already ordered, create a new group each time when value of the second column in the previous record is null, and in each group, add a number column according to the specific requirements. It is a great hassle to try to achieve the process in SQL. You need to first create row numbers and the marker column as needed, and perform the grouping according to the marker column and row numbers. A common alternative is to fetch the original data out of the database and process it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easier to be integrated into a Java program and generate much simpler code. It expresses the algorithm with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =MYSQL.query("select * from t4") |
| 2 | =A1.group@i(#2[-1]==null).run(len=~.len(),~=~.derive(len-#:No_Of_Extensions)).conj() |